# How to get gridview height at runtime

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview whose height property is not set by a css or at runtime. The gridview gets populated at runtime by a random number of records. A simple way to get its height is to count the number of rows. However, sometimes the text is quite large and it wraps up resulting in a larger row height.

Given these facts, is there a way to get gridview height at runtime?

To save you some trouble:

1. Gridview1.Height will return 0.0 since the height property is not determined by a css or at runtime.
2. I know that I could set the row height at a maximum value to cover the cases (if any) when the text wraps up but I do not want that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should add CSS to the tags. The server (running aspnet code) can't know how the client (web browser) will render the page. The problem, as you have described it, is totally client side. HTH

Comment: possible duplicate of [determing the height in pixels of a gridview on an asp.net page at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445431/determing-the-height-in-pixels-of-a-gridview-on-an-asp-net-page-at-runtime)

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes it is the same question like the one you mentioned but since it was old and not answered I figured I should create a new one. Anyway, I guess I 'll have to figure out a javascript way for solving this.

Comment: Would [offsetHeight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733666/how-can-i-calculate-the-rendered-height-of-an-html-table-from-within-javascript) save you?

Comment: Looks promising, I 'll work on it and let you know. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok I just realised that what I want to achieve is not possible. offsetHeight returns the height in pixels but after the gridview is rendered ofcourse. What I want to achieve is to set the height of the parent div according to the child gridview height at runtime (before the gridview is actually rendered) which is not possible. Thanks for your attention.